# Sort dictionary by values, enumerate, and return next largest item from a predetermined item

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to work with a dictionary of unicoded stock tickers and their respective market caps of the S&P 500. I am adding an additional ticker (lets call it ticker STACK), and my end goal is to define a variable with the next largest ticker in the S&P 500 if STACK was added to it. I already have the database and added 'STACK' to it, however, i am unsure how to proceed in correctly managing it.

```
database = {u'AGN': 73.64, u'EOG': 53.83, u'CPB': 14.77, u'EVHC': 5.86, 
u'IDXX': 13.87, u'QRVO': 9.61, u'JWN': 7.77, u'SBAC': 18.05, u'JBHT': 
11.12, u'TAP': 17.03, u'VRTX': 38.73, u'BWA': 10.29....and so on}

for x, y in database.items():  #finds the market cap of STACK
    if x == "STACK":
        stackcap = y

new = list(enumerate(sorted(database.values(), reverse= True)))

print new

#This prints like this: [(0, 474.03), (1, 406.84), (2, 360.86), (3, 
339.27), (4, 322.41), (5, 320.01), (6, 278.76)...etc.]

for x, y in new.items():
    if stackcap == y:
        stackrank = x
    if x == [stackrank+1]:
        nextcap = y

print nextcap
```

For example, if STACK's market cap is 73.65M, I would want to print "AGN" since AGN's market cap is likely the next largest at 73.64M.

The above returns:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if x == [stackrank+1]:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not `stackcap = database['STACK']` ?

Comment: Your second `if` statement does not depend at all on the first one. so that would lead to an error if the first statement is false

Comment: JBernardo - Good point.

Comment: mangoHero1 - I cannot define a variable in an if statement. it is now saying "'stackrank' is not defined. any suggestions?

Comment: @Muricuda it should be indented on the same level as `stackrank = x`

Comment: @mangoHero1 NameError: name 'nextcap' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to find the ticker with the largest cap which is less than the STACK cap? If so, then you can gather the tickers satisfying this constraint and take the maximum of their caps:

```
database = {
    u'AGN': 73.64, u'EOG': 53.83, u'CPB': 14.77, u'EVHC': 5.86, 
    u'IDXX': 13.87, u'QRVO': 9.61, u'JWN': 7.77, u'SBAC': 18.05, 
    u'JBHT': 11.12, u'TAP': 17.03, u'VRTX': 38.73, u'BWA': 10.29,
    u'STACK': 73.65
    }


below_stack = ((t, c) for t, c in database.items() if c < database['STACK'])
next_cap = max(below_stack, key=lambda item: item[1])
print next_cap
```

This will print: `('AGN', 73.64)`.

Comment: You, genius, you,.